# Image view with a top button in cocoa-touch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiimageview, uibutton

i have UIimageView named as myImage.

i need to display a button on the left side of my image view.

however when i am running my app,the image view hiding the button.so cant able to show a button on top of the image view .please can any one help me...

Comment: You are mixing up cocoa-(touch) and xcode. xcode is just an IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the button as a subview of the imageview...

```
[myImageView addSubview:myButton];
```

Then...

```
[myImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
```

Comment: traditionally objective-c uses `YES` and `NO` instead of `TRUE` and `FALSE`

Comment: YES NO TRUE FALSE are all typedefs to the same thing. I totally disagree with this YES NO idea. If(something && somethingElse && !lastThing) equates to 'if something yes and something else yes and lastThing not yes' !?!?! Makes no sense.

Comment: oh and 'traditionally' C uses TRUE / FALSE. ;)

Comment: YES and NO where introduced to Objective-C, before C got a native (actually it is just a typedef of int) boolean type. For me YES and NO makes more sense in Objective-C: question: "set user interaction to enabled" — answer:"yes". But that is not the point. the point is, that all the documentation and xcode template code uses YES/NO. Thats why I wrote my comment, so that future readers will not be confused. you are free to use what ever you feel like.

Comment: code not adding the button to top right corner of myImage View.its coming to center position.help me please

Comment: Just set the frame origin to the relevant CGPoint relative to the parent.

Comment: Ok, CGRect frame = [myButton frame]; frame.origin = CGPointMake(myImageView.frame.size.width - frame.size.width, 0.0f); [myButton setFrame:frame];

Comment: is [myImageView removeSubview:myButton] will remove ?

Comment: That will remove the button from the imageview yes.

Comment: click event is not triggering for the adde3d button